# initial block delaying in verilog

Tags: mips, verilog, clock

When implementing a single cycle mips in Verilog. PC is initialized to address 0 
then updates its value to PC+1 at the posedge of the clock which was also initialized to 0.

The problem is in simulation, the instruction at address 0 takes only half clock cycle then the PC increments by 4 and then the second instruction enters the processor.

[simulation screenshot  http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/36/0cxn.jpg](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/36/0cxn.jpg)

Neither initializing clock by 1 nor adding delays before initializing PC solved the problem

this is my clock module

```
`timescale 1ps / 1ps

module clk_gen( clk );
  output reg clk ;
  initial begin
    clk<=0;
  end

  always begin 
    #1400 clk=!clk;
  end
endmodule
```

PC module:

```
module PC(inPC, Address, clk); 
  input      [31:0] inPC; 
  input             clk; 
  output reg [31:0] Address;   

  initial begin
    Address=32'd0; 
  end 

  always @( posedge clk) begin
    Address <= inPC;
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: module PC(inPC, Address, clk);
 input [31:0] inPC;
 input clk;
 output reg [31:0] Address;
 
 initial
 begin
 
  Address=32'd0;
 end
 



 always @( posedge clk)

 begin
 

  Address <= inPC;

 end


endmodule

Comment: Is there anything that triggers `@(negedge clk)` in the design? Initializing the clock with a non-blocking assignment (`<=`) will always trigger an edge event at time 0.

Comment: Can you post the signal names in the screenshot? Is PC the 4th signal from the top? That is the only signal that is initialized to 0 and then increments to 4, but this happens sometime around 2050. Do you have delays in the datapath?

Comment: yup .. i have delays in the datapath
i made it word addressable.. so it increments by 1 not 4
PC is the second signal .. 
i managed to solve the problem BTW :)
 by adding another module which acts as an " enable " .. initially equals zero and inc to 1 after a while
and added it as a condition to increment PC to manage when the second instruction enters the MIPS 

, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The question does not seem to relate to your clock module but based on that code.

Assuming you are not expect this to be synthesisable. Idealy you defined a `reg` or `logic` value in one process.

NB if your simulator supports it I would define times with absolutes ie `#1.4ns` for your delay.

```
initial begin 
  clk <= 1'b0;
  forever begin
    #1.4ns clk <= ~clk ;
  end
end
```

Comment: in simulation the first instruction takes only half clock cycle .. it's not about the timing

Comment: i posted a scrrenshot of the simualtion
i thought the problem is with my clock generator

Comment: @Fawzinov I am confused you say the problem might be with clock generation, then say the answer is not about timing. We can only answer based on the info given, pretty sure the problem is in the module using the clock. If your comment was about the `#1.4ns` that was just a tip for more reliable/portable/readable code.

Comment: @Fawzinov If an answer helped can you accept it, or post an answer yourself say what you did to fix it. Stackoverflow is a nice way to keep track of common mistakes and might help someone else out.